# Run VBA on smartphone

Tags: vba, office365, galaxy, smartphone

I have searched high and low and I cant find if it is possible to run VBA on Samsung galaxy 5 using Excel 365 (Latest Version)
Was wondering if I take a subscription with 365 will it allow me to use vba
Thanks

Comment: @MatthewD I believe it says there that the web interface (the dumbed down office client) does not support it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@James: Specifically for Android, there is no application which allows you to run VBA, but **e-Droid-Cell Pro Spreadsheet** which includes a "Macro" mechanism allowing to script the application. Although the Macro language is not compatible with VBA (Visual Basic Applications) it does allows for doing almost anything required by a Macro language. Here is the  [Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.j2eeknowledge.viewer.excel.pro&hl=en) of application on Google play store.

They have some really good reviews but I will suggest to try out the trial version first.

As for O365, If you have done any VBA development which works with Office 2010 or Office 2013 then it will work in Office 365, while you can open the book in the browser or through a webpage, you won't be able to run any of the vba code there.

Answer (score 0):

the only solution i found was to install "OpenOffice" on my pc and opening my excel project with vba with OpenOffice, the vba of OpenOffice is near of exel vba **you will need to convert somme instruction** you will be able to convert, débugging and testing on your pc **be sure to save as OpenOffice format**. On your android tablet/phone install "AndrOpen Office" copy your new OpenOffice project to your tablet/phone and open it with AndrOpen Office. **MAKE INTNESIF TEST**

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Sub CreateShahAbdulLatifBhittaiPresentation()
    Dim pptApp As Object
    Dim pptPresentation As Object
    Dim pptSlide As Object
    Dim pptTextbox As Object
    Dim slideIndex As Integer

    ' Create a new PowerPoint application
    Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    pptApp.Visible = True

    ' Add a new presentation
    Set pptPresentation = pptApp.Presentations.Add

    ' Create 10 slides
    For slideIndex = 1 To 10
        ' Add a new slide
        Set pptSlide = pptPresentation.Slides.Add(slideIndex, ppLayoutText)
        
        ' Title for the slide
        pptSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Shah Abdul Latif Bhittai's Lifestyle by Sheikh Ayaz"
        
        ' Add content to the slide
        Set pptTextbox = pptSlide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange
        Select Case slideIndex
            Case 1
                pptTextbox.Text = "Introduction to Shah Abdul Latif Bhittai"
            Case 2
                pptTextbox.Text = "Early Life of Shah Abdul Latif Bhittai"
            Case 3
                pptTextbox.Text = "Sheikh Ayaz's Perspective on Shah Abdul Latif Bhittai"
            Case 4
                pptTextbox.Text = "Bhittai's Literary Contributions"
            ' Add more cases for other slides
        End Select
        
        ' Add images or other media to the slide (use full file path)
        If slideIndex = 3 Then
            pptSlide.Shapes.AddPicture "C:\path\to\image1.jpg", Left:=100, Top:=100, Width:=400, Height:=300
        End If
    Next slideIndex

    ' Save the presentation (provide a path to save it)
    pptPresentation.SaveAs "C:\path\to\save\presentation.pptx"

    ' Clean up
    Set pptTextbox = Nothing
    Set pptSlide = Nothing
    Set pptPresentation = Nothing
    Set pptApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

No, not possible to run vba on mobile even if you take a 365 subscription